# Choose a file from a Webview fragment Android Webview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, webview, android-webview

I have a webview fragment and the webpage has an upload image button. When I tap the button no file chooser appears. Wondering if somebody can assist with this, I am new to android development. I have attached the Homefragment which contains the webview code.

Note I have a navigation drawer and nearly 10 tabs (Fragments) each has its own webview url

```
    package com.test.test.ui.home;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.test.test.R;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private WebView webView;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        webView = (WebView)root.findViewById(R.id.webviewHome);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(getActivity()), "Android");

        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.testwebsite.co.uk/view-home");



        return root;
    }

    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast() {

        }
    }
}
```

in my Manifest, I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

[image: Upload button from the webpage]

Comment: are you sure that the problem from webView? maybe it's a bug in the web site? just asking.

Comment: The site is fine, I used an app builder and it works on the currently deployed app as well. But I have decided to rebuild the app myself. The site functions all work correctly

Comment: https://medium.com/@adsl99801/app-webview-upload-image-770a0ffd7aad
check this blog i hope help you